# "const std::stop_token&" or just "std::stop_token" as parameter for thread function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

Since clang-tidy was complaining about "The parameter 'stop_token' is copied for each invocation but only used as a const reference; consider making it a const reference" I was asking myself the question, why every example I find about std::jthread/stop_token takes the stop_token by value, but I did not find any explanation for it.

So, why take the stop_token by value?

```
1) void f(std::stop_token){};
2) void f(const std::stop_token&){};
```

Does it really matter when you can assume that the stop_token is the one generated by std::jthread?

edit: This is asked purely out of curiosity and to not ignore a clang-tidy warning "just because".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/jthread),

> Creates new jthread object and associates it with a thread of execution. The new thread of execution starts executing
>
> `std::invoke(std::move(f_copy), get_stop_token(), std::move(args_copy)...)`, ...

And the return type of [`std::jthread::get_stop_token`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/get_stop_token) is `std::stop_token`.

So, if your `f` is only used to construct a `std::jthread`, I believe it's **totally ok** to be with a `const std::stop_token&` as its first parameter. There's no lifetime issue.

But if you want to use your `f` in other places, `std::thread` for example, there may be a problem.

```cpp
void f(const std::stop_token&) {}
{
    std::stop_source ssrc;
    std::stop_token stk{ssrc.get_token()};
    std::thread t{f, std::ref(stk)};
}
```

When `stk` gets destroyed, the reference is dangled.

---

In **most** cases, you should pass by value.

Because copying `std::stop_token` and `std::stop_source` is relative cheap. 
Also, since `std::token` is usually stored in a lambda and/or used in another thread, passing by value can avoid lifetime issues.

There're also some cases where you could pass by reference.

Since it's not that cheap compared to raw pointers. It'll be more efficient to pass by reference if you can guarantee the lifetime.

For example, [`std::stop_callback`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_callback/stop_callback), because it'll copy `std::stop_token` inside, pass by reference will be better.

```
template<class C>
explicit stop_callback( const std::stop_token& st, C&& cb ) noexcept(/*see below*/);
```

Comment: I think your answer has more information in it than what was asked for. Is it valid to shorten it to "it does not matter"?

Comment: No, it matters... I'll update it. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: If there is a possible lifetime-issue even with the "auto-generated" stop_token from std::jthread that would be a very good reason for always copying the stop_token. I just fail to come up with one.

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Emmm.. I think it's totally ok for jthread to accept a function whose first parameter is `const std::stop_token&` since the argument is `std::jthread::get_stop_token`, already a copy. I'll take a look a bit later.

Comment: Updated with some clarifications.

Comment: I think your last edit is a good explanation as to why it is fine to use a const&.

Comment: I've just verified with the version 12 of gcc's C++ library, and the data associated to a `std::stop_source` is a `_Stop_state_t*`, a pointer. In that case, passing by copy would be better.